# How to create tables in Hybris without init?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Some time ago two new types were created without deployment tables and their items were stored in `ComposedType`'s table. After a while, this problem was noticed and deployment tables were added to `*-items.xml` but these two tables aren't created during `update`. How can I handle this problem? Unfortunately, I can't use `init` on our environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define two new itemtypes with the desired deployment table in the items.xml and perform system update. Then, you need to import the data from the two old itemtypes to the new itemtypes. Finally, you need to delete the old columns using SQL command and clear the orphaned types from hAC.